# Why do I get a behavior difference when calling .last on has_many through associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

I'm pretty new to Rails dev. I have quite a few has_many through associations in my project and they've always worked as expected when I call .last until this most recent has_many through relationship I just created.

Setting a breakpoint and calling some values in the console I get what I expect with the following query:

(byebug) current_user.account_states.last

```
#<AccountState id: 1, state: 0, description: "account ok", created_at: "2016-01-25 19:19:36", updated_at: "2016-01-25 19:19:36">
```

But when I make a similar query on my new has_many relationship I do not get what I want. First of all, it always issues a SQL query, which is curious to me. Second, and more importantly, it does not give the result I'm looking for because it sorts on dropsite id. I expected to get results for "My Store" rather than "Janell's". See the following:

(byebug) current_user.dropsites.last

```
  Dropsite Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "dropsites".* 
  FROM "dropsites" INNER JOIN "user_dropsites" 
  ON "dropsites"."id" = "user_dropsites"."dropsite_id" 
  WHERE "user_dropsites"."user_id" = ?  
  ORDER BY "dropsites"."id" DESC 
  LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 6]]
```

```
#<Dropsite id: 3, name: "Janell's", phone: "2065551212", hours: "7-7, M-F", address: "1234 Main St.", access_instructions: "just walk in", created_at: "2016-01-25 21:09:10", updated_at: "2016-01-27 19:30:07", active: true, city: "Boise", state: "ID", zip: 83701>
```

I was able to get the data I wanted by using:

```
Dropsite.find(current_user.dropsites.joins(:user_dropsites).order('user_dropsites.created_at').last.id)
```

But I'm wanting to better understand why rails exhibits different behavior in these two cases so that I can control my code better.

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.2p95. I've tried searching hi and lo but can't seem to find the information I'm lacking to be able to figure this one out on my own. Any pointers/ideas would be much appreciated!

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_account_states
  has_many :account_states, through: :user_account_states
  has_many :user_dropsites
  has_many :dropsites, through: :user_dropsites
end

class AccountState < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_account_states
  has_many :users, through: :user_account_states
end

class UserAccountState < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account_state
  belongs_to :user
end

class Dropsite < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_dropsites
  has_many :users, through: :user_dropsites
end

class UserDropsite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dropsite
  belongs_to :user  
end
```

Here is my table data:

```
AccountState table data:
"id", "state", "description", "created_at", "updated_at"
"1", "0", "account ok", "2016-01-25 19:19:36.622125", "2016-01-25 19:19:36.622125"
"2", "1", "account on hold", "2016-01-25 19:19:36.639550", "2016-01-25 19:19:36.639550"

UserAccountState table data:
"account_state_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "notes"
"2", "6", "2016-01-27 18:08:55.593669", "2016-01-27 18:08:55.593669", ""
"1", "6", "2016-01-27 18:13:44.831515", "2016-01-27 18:13:44.831515", ""

Dropsite table data:
"id", "name", "phone", "hours", "address", "access_instructions", "created_at", "updated_at", "active", "city", "state", "zip"
"1", "My Store", "213-412-5709", "24x7x365", "5719 54rd Court NE", "", "2016-01-25 21:00:21.318115", "2016-01-27 19:29:29.300511", "t", "Tallahassee", "FL", "32300"
"3", "Janell's", "2065551212", "7-7, M-F", "1234 Main St.", "just walk in", "2016-01-25 21:09:10.337827", "2016-01-27 19:30:07.106183", "t", "Boise", "ID", "83701"

UserDropsite table data:
"user_id", "dropsite_id", "created_at", "updated_at"
"6", "3", "2016-01-26 21:43:10.154020", "2016-01-26 21:43:10.154020"
"6", "1", "2016-01-27 18:24:45.927775", "2016-01-27 18:24:45.927775"
```

Comment: I read your question twice and cannot figure out what's your expectation on `.last`?

Comment: As an aside, are you really storing zip codes as numbers (i.e. `zip: 83701`)? They're not numbers, they're strings that just happen to contain digits.

Comment: Isn't `Dropsite.find(current_user.dropsites.joins(:user_dropsites).order('user_dropsites.created_at').last.id)` equivalent to `current_user.dropsites.joins(:user_dropsites).order('user_dropsites.created_at').last`? Why would you `find` a record you've already found?

Comment: @Leito, thanks for having a look. As mentioned in the question "I expected to get results for "My Store" rather than "Janell's"". In the Dropsite table "My Store" is added prior to "Janell's" but in the UserDropsite table it's the other way around. I'm expecting current_user.dropsites.last to return the dropsite associated with the last result in the join table..."My Store". And this is what happens when I call current_user.account_states.last. I just can't figure out why it doesn't happen that same way when calling current_user.dropsites.last. Regarding zips...yeah, my bad. Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan to your first question, idk, probably. I suck at ruby joins/queries. Right now, to me, it doesn't matter if they are equivalent because all I want is to get the most recent dropsite the user has specified to use in a manner consistent with the rest of my code, a la current_user.dropsites.last. I don't think I understand your second question.

Comment: The second question is rhetorical. You wouldn't `find` a record you've already found, but that's what your code is doing.